# Django CreateView - ignores defaults on POST-test

Tags: python, django

I have a simple create view for a simple model with default-value fields. I want to test this setup by supplying only fields which don't have a default value.
The test fails, because no object was created in the database. Having played around with prints, I know the following:
The models clean() passes, and is supplied with the default values.
The response claims "This field is required." for maxVar and minVotes.
(And sending both values lets the tests pass.)

The failing test is:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
import datetime

from testcase.models import Poll

class PollCreateTest(TestCase):
    def test_create_with_description_only(self):
       """description should be sufficient to create a poll."""
        self.assertEqual(Poll.objects.count(), 0)
        x = self.client.post(reverse('rating:create'), {'description':'A Poll'})
        #print x
        self.assertEqual(Poll.objects.count(), 1)
```

With corresponding models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Poll(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    minVotes = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    maxVar = models.FloatField(default = 0.0)
    finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic

from .models import Poll

class CreateView(generic.edit.CreateView):
    model=Poll
    fields=['description', 'maxVar', 'minVotes']
```

I am trying to get myself familiar with Django. The problem can probably be solved by writing a FormView with custom clean() methods. But I would like to understand WHY this doesn't work and, ideally, how to solve the problem.

I use Django 1.8 with Python 2.7.8.

Comment: Could you include the versions of Django and Python that you're working on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial value is only used for two purposes: to render the initial value in the html form input, and to see if the submitted value has changed. It is not used to validate the form: not passing the actual data to the form is the same as explicitly changing the initial data to an empty value.

As your `maxVar` and `minVotes` fields are required (they don't have `blank=True`), deleting the initial values and passing no data to the form is not allowed. You have to pass both of them if you want the form to validate.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.
Is there a standard way to test the minimum fields a user has to set, without doing live-server tests?